# How to update Gapps in Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, google, twrp

I am running cyanogenmod 12.1 with Gapps outdated version. So, I want to replace the actual version to the newest. I already downloaded de correct one. I would like to know the installation procedure using TWRP Recovery.

Comment: Take Nandroid backup first and then flash the GAPPS file.

Comment: Does TWRP backup count?

Comment: The backup you make using your custom recovery is called Nandroid backup. Nand is the flash type storage  and a custom recovery simply take an image of the partition as backup.

Comment: Right! So, should I install the newest version over the oldest, without removing anything?

Comment: Yes. Just remember to backup first.